# Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS problem

Tags: 12.04, server, proxy

Today I installed Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS i386 version on my old AMD Athlon 2000+ PC... The thing is I don't have access to internet. I cant even execute sudo apt-get update... An I cant ping www.google.com

During installation I put the local IP 192.168.1.175, Subnet 255.255.255.0, nameserver from my ISP 194.146.109.223 and I left PROXY empty and I jut pressed enter after the proxy. Now I don't have any acces to internet from server and I can't update my machine...

Is it because I didn't put any PROXY address???

Comment: Are you bihind a proxy? Can you provide info about the internet connection.

Comment: As above, please edit the question to include information about your networking hardware (`lspci -nn | grep net`) and let us know how your network is configured. I suspect you've set a static IP and your router wants to give you a dynamic IP.

Comment: 00:0d.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor RTL-8139 (rev 10)

Comment: 00:13.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor RTL-8139 (rev 10)

Comment: I logged into my router and configured manually that my DHCP always gives me IP 192.168.1.175 for my server. Even during installation I set IP for server 192.168.1.175

Comment: During installation Ubuntu asked me for domain and I put his for my home domain server.home.org

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above, it sounds like you've configured something you should have left as automatic. I would run `sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces` and make the file look something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Save that and run `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` or `sudo restart networking` (I can't remember if 12.04 is Upstart-converted). Assumign the ethernet device is supported, that should tell it to ask for a dynamic IP.

If you want to statically assign an IP (often a desirable thing for a server) I would get the DHCP server on the router to set your server's IP to the same thing each time. Most routers allow this sort of soft-static addressing by MAC address.

Comment: I ran sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces and this is what my data says:sudoedit /etc/network/interfacesnet static
address 192.168.1.175
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
#dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
dns-nameservers 194.146.109.223
dns-search server.home.org


auto eth0
iface eth0 i

Comment: I assigned IP for server na router manually: 192.168.1.175

Comment: Now when I ping 192.168.1.1 it says Destionation Host Unreachable

Comment: Now I cant see my server on router